# rails ruby method invocation by Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on rails app and have stumbled upon stupid yet simple problem. I need to invoke ruby method by triggering javascript button. I have a controller called Book and I'm placing method inside BooksHelper. What I want to do is simply trigger the execution of this method by button click which would output the result on the same page, I don't want that method opening another page. I've checked couple possible solutions but can't make them work. None of those methods in example.html.erb actually work. I would like to get help on how to fix the problem. 
It only works if I wrap up in alert method, but that's not what I want. I want the output to be printed out in the actual page. So, how can I do it? I've read the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html but it doesnt answer my question, since I'm not looking for creating new pages with controller and routes, but rather executing a ruby method in order to see result on the same page. Thank you!

```
<%= button_to_function "Output", "alert('#{outputString}')" %>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#app/helpers/book_helper.rb
   module BooksHelper
     def outputString
        "output"
 end
   end

-----------------------------------------------------

#app/controllers/books_controller.rb
   class PagesController < ApplicationController
      def outputString

       end
   end
  ------------------------------------------------------

  #app/views/books/example.html.erb

   <%= button_to_function "Print", "outputString" %>

   <%= button_to "Print", :action => "outputString" %>

   <input class="ok" onclick="outputString()" type="button" value="Print" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller/helper method `outputString` isn't available client-side once your templates are rendered.

`button_to_function` is for calling javascript functions via button click.  You cannot call server-side functions directly from a javascript button without making an AJAX request back to the server.

Comment: So, this problem is only solved via AJAX? no other option? I have no knowledge of AJAX unfortunately, guess will have to learn it now..Thanks!

Comment: @user2928354, yep, you're looking at a [remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). And yep, it uses AJAX.

Comment: Yes, look at it like the Rails code is server-side and the views are rendered and executed client-side.   So when this html is sent down to the client (browser) and they click the button they are client-side, they dont have access to functions that only live on the server in server-side code.